# How can I separate out an ASP.NET Web API controller's SQL Server database access?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, permissions, application-pool

We're investigating migrating from WCF to Web API.

One of the ways we had WCF set up was to use multiple URL endpoints as separate web applications in IIS. So for example

```
http://site/service1/service1.svc
http://site/service2/service2.svc
http://site/service3/service3.svc
```

That sort of thing.

The big goal/advantage of this approach was that we could separate each web application into its own application pool, which then would allow us to restrict that service into its own database. So, the Service1 web application would be part of the Service1 application pool which would run under the DOMAIN\Service1 identity which would then be restricted to accessing the Service1 database under SQL server.

This affords several advantages, including what happens when [Jimmy](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) tries to access Service2's database from Service1's code.

Now we're looking at moving to Web API and one of the things that's appealing is that what we were previously doing as "services" (and thus in a bunch of separate projects) could just be controllers off of one main project, or at least that's one possibility.

The problem is that we'd be losing the ability to separate out services (would now be controllers) by application pools since as it stands now the entire project would be under one web application in IIS. The only other options using application pools would be to either part it out via web applications that intercept the URL (not even sure if that's possible) or put every service under its own project, which would sort of defeat the purpose.

I searched to see if there was a way to do what we were doing under Web API and I'm not finding much at all which either means no one else is doing what we're doing or there's a much better way to handle this that I'm not familiar with.

**To be clear**: I'm not talking about restricting an end user's access to a particular controller or method (I know there's a whole different set of concerns there) and I'm not talking about reading metadata about Web API from a controller, I'm just trying to see if there's a good way to separate out database access within a Web API project itself, and the direction I was leaning was wondering if there's a way to discern it at the controller level.

Comment: You can still host 3 different applications under a single site, just like you did with WCF

Comment: So do I just make IIS "applications" that mirror the URL structure I'm going for?

Comment: That's the idea. If you want them to run completely isolated, then that's how you do it.